# What are the differences between the different ports of MW3?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

First off let me say this question is being asked with the assumption that computer specs meet all the recommended specs for the game.

When I had purchased *Black Ops* from Steam for PC my computer went well beyond the recommended specs, but I had all sorts of problems occur such as crashes in the game causing it to force quit itself, as well as having the game screen go to a bright yellow and not returning to the game itself.

What are the differences between the various ports of the game?

Comment: @Wipqozn There's been discussion on chat about this

Comment: @badp okay, I'll delete my comments and look there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of really good comparison videos that have been done, but [this article](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-face-off-modern-warfare-3) summarizes the differences and shows a bunch of different videos of different versions of the game.

If you're looking for a quick heads-up comparison of the video quality, check out this YouTube video: